# Console.WriteLine vs Print

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know this might sound like a really dumb question, but I am rather confused and can only find answers to the question 'WriteLine vs debug.log' instead of this one. I originally started using Visual Studio where I learned to use Console.WriteLine ("example text");  to show a sentence on the screen, however I have started to use Unity and there I am shown to use simply print ("example text");

Is it just down to preference which one I should use? Do they both do the same thing, in the same way that the difference between 'int' and 'decimal' is sometimes not always noticeable? Or do I use them like this depending on what program I am using? If the latter is the case, does this not defeat the purpose of it being a language if I have to change the way I use it depending which program I am using.

Apologies if this seems like such an irrelevant question but I'd rather be sure rather than continue having dismissed it and doing things wrong further down because of it.

Comment: `Console` comes from the core libraries of the .NET Framework. `print` is a Unity Editor method with special support for Unity classes. If you want to be able to run your code outside Unity, you won't be able to use `print`

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Would there usually be any need to run it outside Unity? Assuming there are other methods I would have to also change, wouldn't it be a long process of editing code just so I can run it elsewhere?

Comment: You would use `Console.WriteLine()` in own written libraries that could be used outside of Unity, potentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Unity code, I recommend using the static methods in the [`Debug`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.html) class, such as [`Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html), [`Debug.LogFormat`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.LogFormat.html), etc.

There are other variations on these methods such as [`Debug.LogWarning`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.LogWarning.html) and [`Debug.LogError`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.LogError.html) which you can find listed in the first link above. In the Editor you can use the buttons above the log panel to filter the log to only show the messages you want, for example errors only if there is too much noise from your other log messages.

Unity's [`MonoBehaviour.print`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour-print.html) method is a thin wrapper around `Debug.Log` that has two drawbacks:

- It's missing some of the features of the above methods, such as the ability to pass a `context` argument that ties the debug message to the object in the Unity Editor, and the ability to filter by log type in the Editor.
- It's a method of `MonoBehaviour`, so you can *only* use it in classes derived from that. The `Debug` methods can be used in any of your Unity code.

It's also worth noting that all of these log methods are available in a runtime build as well as in the Editor. When they are called in a build, the log messages are available in the `MyAppName_Data/output_log.txt` file, where `MyAppName` is the name of your executable.

Be careful to not leave too many logging calls in your code when you make a runtime build, especially in methods that are called in every frame like your `Update` methods. You can use [`Application.isEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isEditor.html) to test whether you're running in the editor or not.

It's also possible to use [platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) for this. This saves a bit of space at runtime, but it is trickier. For example, you might think that `UNITY_EDITOR` means you're running in the Editor, but it is also defined in runtime builds!